# Grounding one port of SPDT analog switch

Tags: grounding, multiplexer, analog-switch

We are using a micro-controller to interface RGB matrix (HUB75 connector). Matrix row can be selected using signal pins (A-E). Some RGB matrix suppliers require to use (CLK/DIN/OE) on (A/B/C) pins to serially select/shift row. Pins (D/E) are connected to ground.

When we want to use first type, R1/R2 are soldered down, while R3/R4 are removed.
When we want to use second type, R1/R2 are removed, while R3/R4 are soldered with 0 Ohm.

This require to know in advance which matrix type will be used before releasing PCB (figure 1).

We would like to use analog switches so the matrix type can be selected in the field as in figure 2.

(1) Is it right to use analog switch in order to ground the two pins if connecting second type?

(2) Will the switch resistance (~6 Ohm) have effect since both sides are connected to ground. second type.

(3) Will the switch affect signals at ~20MHz?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: in the situation when you are grounding out R3/R4, possibly no need to remove R1/R2, since the connection to ground will dominate the resulting voltage. Analog switch might even be too complicated, depending on signal type (input thresholds for the HUB75E), something as simple as a transistor could be used to ground out R3/R4

Comment: Your point is valid when i want to continue manual switching. It does not solve auto switching, however.

Comment: if the HUB75E is taking the usual cmos logic inputs, simply drive the transistor from your control signal. you can even use a diode. With the transistor, output signal levels will be similar to the answer below using the AND gate, although that is neater in a way. all of these methods very cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use an analog switch in this way. For digital 20 MHz signals, the switch resistance and capacitance will not have any noticeable effect.

However, analog switches are more complexity than actually required, and when the D/E signals already are grounded, you do not need connect them to anything. The output is either the same as the input, or disabled; you can implement this logic with a three-state buffer. There are two-channel devices like the (SN)74LVC2G125; use 2× (SN)74AHCT1G125 if the control signal uses TTL voltage levels.

Comment: The problem is that pins D/E are grounded by manufacturer as stated. Will it damage the '08 gate if its output grounded, even its output is zero?

Comment: No. And it is pointless to make a connection from ground to ground; you should use '125 instead.

Comment: this is a good advice. accepted. I will use 1G125 instead.